# Solucionar error header(Location....)

Tags: php, html, headers, fixedheader

he tenido problemas al implementar los update dentro de mi sitio. Al momento de ejecutar la consulta dentro del programa actualiza los campos requeridos tanto en el sitio como dentro de la BD, el problema radica en la redirección de la página php desde que se actualizaron los campos hasta que los muestra en la página correspondiente.
El error mostrado en cuestión es el siguiente:
"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\representacionesv5\Administrador\Mantenedor\Tribunales\update.php:4) in C:\xampp\htdocs\representacionesv5\Administrador\Mantenedor\Tribunales\update.php on line 122"

la página php correspondiente al update.php está estructurado de la siguiente forma:

```html
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id_tribunal'])) 
{
  $id=$_GET['id_tribunal'];
      
  $select="SELECT * FROM `tribunal` WHERE id_tribunal='$id'";
  $resultadoSelect = mysqli_query($conexion, $select);
       
  if (mysqli_num_rows($resultadoSelect) == 1) 
    {              
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoSelect);
      $idTribunal = $row['id_tribunal'];
      $nombreTribunal = $row['nombre'];
      $juridiccionTribunal = $row['juridiccion'];
      $secretarioribunal = $row['secretario'];
      $juezTribunal = $row['juez'];
      $telefonoTribunal = $row['telefono'];
      $ordenTribunal = $row['orden'];
    }           
}
       
       
if (isset($_POST['btn_guardar'])) 
  {

    $idtribunal1=$_GET['id_tribunal'];

           
                 
    $nombreTribunal1=$_POST['txt_nom'];
    $juridiccionTribunal1=$_POST['txt_jur'];     
    $secretarioTribunal1=$_POST['txt_sec'];   
    $juezTribunal1=$_POST['txt_jue'];
    $telefonoTribunal1=$_POST['txt_tel'];
    $ordenTribunal1=$_POST['txt_ord']; 

    $update = "UPDATE `tribunal` SET `nombre`='$nombreTribunal1',`juridiccion`='$juridiccionTribunal1',
                      `secretario`='$secretarioTribunal1',`juez`='$juezTribunal1',`telefono`='$telefonoTribunal1',
                      `orden`='$ordenTribunal1' WHERE id_tribunal='$idtribunal1'";
       
    
    $resultadoUpdate=mysqli_query($conexion, $update);
     
    header("Location: tribunales.php");
  }

?>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Row Formulario -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-md-12 m-1">
        <h1>Tribunales</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center col-md-12 m-1">
            <form class="bg-dark text-white border border-solid rounded m-3" action="update.php?id_tribunal=<?php echo $_GET['id_tribunal'];?>" method="POST" >
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center col-md-12">
                     <div class="form-group">
                       <legend class="m-2">
                         Formulario Actualizacion
                       </legend>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                     <label for="">Id Tribunal</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_id" id="txt_id" autofocus value="<?php echo $idTribunal;?>" readonly>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                     <label for="">Nombre Tribunal</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_nom" id="txt_nom" value="<?php echo $nombreTribunal;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <label for="">Juridicción Tribunal</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_jur" id="txt_jur" value="<?php echo $juridiccionTribunal;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <label for="">Secretario Tribunal</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_sec" id="txt_sec" value="<?php echo $secretarioribunal;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <label for="">Juez Tribunal</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_jue" id="txt_jue" value="<?php echo $juezTribunal;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <label for="">Telefono Tribunal</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text"               name="txt_tel" id="txt_tel" value="<?php echo $telefonoTribunal;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <label for="">Orden Tribunal</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_ord" id="txt_ord" value="<?php echo $ordenTribunal;?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group m-2">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-success form-control btn-lg" name="btn_guardar">Actualizar</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

la línea de código que presenta el error es el siguiente:

```html
header("Location: tribunales.php");
```

el funcionamiento normal sería desde las páginas tribunales.php hacia update.php y redireccionar hacia tribunales.php nuevamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando envías cabeceras (`header`) no debe salir nada por pantalla antes de las cabeceras, porque si esto ocurre, los `header` se enviarán de forma implícita.

El [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) es muy claro al respecto:

> Recuerde que `header()` debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por
> pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde
> PHP. Es un error muy común leer código con funciones como `include` o
> `require`, u otro tipo de funciones de acceso de ficheros que incluyen
> espacios o líneas en blanco que se muestran antes de llamar a la
> función `header()`. Sucede el mismo problema cuando se utiliza un solo
> fichero PHP/HTML.

Lo que te está diciendo el mensaje:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> C:\xampp\htdocs\representacionesv5\Administrador\Mantenedor\Tribunales\update.php:4)

Es que algo se imprimió en la línea 4 del archivo `update.php`. Si tú quieres enviar las cabeceras en la línea 122 del mismo archivo, debes controlar lo que está pasando en la línea 4 e impedir que se imprima algo ahí.

Esto mismo vale para cualquier otra salida que haya antes de mandar el header.

Comment: muchas gracias por su respuesta, gracias a esa observación y revisando el código me di cuenta del error.

Answer (score 1):

Termina la ejecución del código con `return` para que acepte la redirección por header.

```
  <?php
    
    if (isset($_GET['id_tribunal'])) 
    {
      $id=$_GET['id_tribunal'];
          
      $select="SELECT * FROM `tribunal` WHERE id_tribunal='$id'";
      $resultadoSelect = mysqli_query($conexion, $select);
           
      if (mysqli_num_rows($resultadoSelect) == 1) 
        {              
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoSelect);
          $idTribunal = $row['id_tribunal'];
          $nombreTribunal = $row['nombre'];
          $juridiccionTribunal = $row['juridiccion'];
          $secretarioribunal = $row['secretario'];
          $juezTribunal = $row['juez'];
          $telefonoTribunal = $row['telefono'];
          $ordenTribunal = $row['orden'];
        }           
    }
           
           
    if (isset($_POST['btn_guardar'])) 
      {
    
        $idtribunal1=$_GET['id_tribunal'];
    
               
                     
        $nombreTribunal1=$_POST['txt_nom'];
        $juridiccionTribunal1=$_POST['txt_jur'];     
        $secretarioTribunal1=$_POST['txt_sec'];   
        $juezTribunal1=$_POST['txt_jue'];
        $telefonoTribunal1=$_POST['txt_tel'];
        $ordenTribunal1=$_POST['txt_ord']; 
    
        $update = "UPDATE `tribunal` SET `nombre`='$nombreTribunal1',`juridiccion`='$juridiccionTribunal1',
                          `secretario`='$secretarioTribunal1',`juez`='$juezTribunal1',`telefono`='$telefonoTribunal1',
                          `orden`='$ordenTribunal1' WHERE id_tribunal='$idtribunal1'";
           
        
        $resultadoUpdate=mysqli_query($conexion, $update);
         
        header("Location: tribunales.php");
        return;    
      }
    
    ?>
    
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Row Formulario -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-md-12 m-1">
            <h1>Tribunales</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center col-md-12 m-1">
                <form class="bg-dark text-white border border-solid rounded m-3" action="update.php?id_tribunal=<?php echo $_GET['id_tribunal'];?>" method="POST" >
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center col-md-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <legend class="m-2">
                             Formulario Actualizacion
                           </legend>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group m-2">
                         <label for="">Id Tribunal</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_id" id="txt_id" autofocus value="<?php echo $idTribunal;?>" readonly>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group m-2">
                         <label for="">Nombre Tribunal</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_nom" id="txt_nom" value="<?php echo $nombreTribunal;?>">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group m-2">
                          <label for="">Juridicción Tribunal</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_jur" id="txt_jur" value="<?php echo $juridiccionTribunal;?>">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group m-2">
                          <label for="">Secretario Tribunal</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_sec" id="txt_sec" value="<?php echo $secretarioribunal;?>">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group m-2">
                          <label for="">Juez Tribunal</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_jue" id="txt_jue" value="<?php echo $juezTribunal;?>">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center g-5">
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group m-2">
                          <label for="">Telefono Tribunal</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text"               name="txt_tel" id="txt_tel" value="<?php echo $telefonoTribunal;?>">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group m-2">
                          <label for="">Orden Tribunal</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txt_ord" id="txt_ord" value="<?php echo $ordenTribunal;?>">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group m-2">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-success form-control btn-lg" name="btn_guardar">Actualizar</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por su respuesta

Comment: De Nada Para Eso Estamos